# PCL Build 1.7 on windows 7 x64, vs10

Tags: boost, cmake, kinect, point-cloud-library

hi! Help me please to build pcl 1.7 on windows 7 x64, vs10. As i know there are not 3rd party dependencies. such as boost, vtk etc. so first of all i want to build and install boost 1.55. there are also no cmake config files and cmakelists in boost. It needs for me to run pcl 3D recognition example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your question is quite general, you get a general answer...

PCL has a good tutorial on [how to build PCL on Windows](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/compiling_pcl_windows.php#compiling-pcl-windows).

There **are** dependencies on other software. There is also a tutorial on [how to build them from source](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/compiling_pcl_dependencies_windows.php#compiling-pcl-dependencies-windows).

Have you done those tutorials and still have problems? If yes, be more precise.